# How to control text and td element sizes and positions on a responsive table?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a responsive header with the size moving from 280x50px to 1280x150px. I'm having the following troubles:

1. I'm not able to limit the sizes of the `td` elements (and the text within them) to the limit specified above.
2. How to find out the exact cut off font size (px) for a smooth transitioning from vw to a fixed size?
3. Is it possible to overlap two `td` elements? In the code, the gap between the texts "letter case" and "LETTER CASE" is big and I want to reduce it by lowering the position of the "letter case" text so that it sit just slightly above the "LETTER CASE" text.

I've tried many different ways to do it for two whole days and I'm at my wits end. The closest I did was by wrapping the texts inside `div` elements and re-positioning the "lower case" text using `margin`. But the result was messy when tested for responsiveness.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    div {
      outline: 1px solid green;
    }
    
    table {
      outline: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    td {
      outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Modak';
      src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Modak&display=swap);
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Audiowide';
      src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide&display=swap);
    }
    
    #header {
      margin: auto;
      min-width: 280px;
      max-width: 1280px;
      min-height: 50px;
      max-height: 150px;
    }
    
    #table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: auto;
      min-width: 280px;
      max-width: 1280px;
      min-height: 50px;
      max-height: 150px;
    }
    
    #image {
      background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/512);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      min-width: 50px;
      min-height: 50px;
      max-width: 150px;
      max-height: 150px;
      width: 17vw;
      height: 17vw;
    }
    
    #lower {
      font-family: 'Modak';
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333092, #EC008C);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      text-align: right;
      min-height: 25px;
      max-height: 75px;
      font-size: 6vw;
    }
    
    #upper {
      font-family: 'Audiowide';
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00AEEF, #333092);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      text-align: right;
      min-height: 25px;
      max-height: 75px;
      font-size: 6vw;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 75px) {
      #lower {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      #upper {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" id="image"></td>
        <td id="lower"><strong>letter case</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="upper">LETTER CASE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @media screen and (max-height: 75px) for which device?

Comment: Browsers on pc, laptop and smartphones? I'm a complete novice so my code is definitely messed up.